# How to print Firebase data in a listview in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve Firebase values into a list view in my app.

I have a database structure like this. [image: my database structure]

When I run the code, in my app I see an empty page, but in my Android Studio console I see a **System.out: dsdstytytyty** which is the last value on that structure. I added those values manually out of curiosity.

My questions

1. Why does my code only detect the last two values amount and item?
2. Why does it print them in the Android Studio console and not in my app?
3. Does the unique identifier which acts as a title to the Dog Expenditure child play a role in this?

Code for retrieving the values.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mystatement);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        dref= dref.child("Dog Expenditure");

        dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String, String>) child.getValue();
                    String amount = child.get("amount").toString();
                    String item = value.get("item").toString();
                    // This will print out amount and item
                    System.out.println(amount + item);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        }
```

Even when I try to do a **System.out.println("Test letters to see if it would output in my app");** nothing happens just a blank page shows.

Answer (score 0):

Add addChildEvent Listener .

Try ,

```
 dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String a = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue()
            System.out.println(a);

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. I can guess that its happening since there are other nods inside and jsut two params (2 strings). see next..
2. Try to debug with breakpoints. see whats inside of dataSnapshot. It will help you understand what to do with it.

To get values from inner nodes, you need to go to each node like this   dataSnapshot.child("-KeyM5446414564").getValue

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the values from the dataset the wrong way

try this

```
GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>> gti = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>>(){};
                    Map<String, String> value= dataSnapshot.getValue(gti);
```

you can read this for more info
https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/GenericTypeIndicator.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need declare your listView inside onDatachange, then set adapter of listView. Read this article [tutorial link to retrieve data from Firebase](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-crud/)

Answer (score -1):

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    android.R.id.text1
);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please explain what the above code snippet does, possibly with the proper documentation, and how it helps solving the issue.

Comment: +1 @TimVisée: I too felt the same. Almustapha: Please provide your answer with clear descriptions. Don't share the link/code blindly, give the explanation/glimpse about the link/code which you have shared, so that others can also understand and it will be helpful

Comment: Likewise, all this code does is create a simple `ArrayAdapter` for a `ListView`. This answer does not address the question at all.